# Custom main entry point parameters from the command line in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I saw somewhere online someone showing what appeared to be valid C# code. It allowed for custom parameters in the main method to be passed as command-line arguments. It looked something like this:

```cs
static void Main(FileInfo input, int maxSize = 9, bool someflag = false)
{
    // code
}
```

This could be used in the command line like this:

```sh
$ myApp hello_world.txt --maxSize 10 --someflag
```

Is this actually possible, or is someone pulling my leg?

Comment: The c# runtime doesn't know how to map custom command line arguments into anything other than a `string[]`. You can write custom code to parse that for you into objects, but not on the `Main` method.

Comment: Huh, I assumed that this was a new feature in C# 9 or something, judging by the way the guy was talking about it

Comment: Do you have the source for this example? E.g. maybe they were using some sort of custom build step to rewrite the assembly into translating a normal Main into this?

Comment: Are you sure that was the only overload of `Main()`?  Although, declaring that alongside a proper `Main()` or `Main(string[] args)` produces the warning "warning CS0028: 'Program.Main(FileInfo, int, bool)' has the wrong signature to be an entry point."

Comment: I've added the screenshot someone sent me

Comment: This question seems related to MSDN Magazine article [Parse the Command Line with System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can with [DragonFruit](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/wiki/DragonFruit-overview), a (currently) **alpha** feature of the dotnet CLI.

> Interpreting the `string[]` arguments into behaviors has been left as a task for the developer. Did the user ask for help? Did they pass invalid input? Can the input be converted to the types that you need if they're not `string`? These problems are not solved for you.

> What if you could declare a strongly-typed `Main` method? This was the question that led to the creation of the experimental app model called "DragonFruit", which allows you to create an entry point with multiple parameters of various types and using default values [...]

Here's a tutorial:
https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/Your-first-app-with-System-CommandLine-DragonFruit.md

Comment: Build and get this error: "Program.Main(int, bool, FileInfo)' has the wrong signature to be an entry point"